# Model with unique attribute is being created twice

Tags: node.js, sails.js, passport.js, sails-mongo

I am using [this passport-generate-auth](https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth) module, and I am trying to get my grasp around understanding this whole thing.

So, in my `User` model, I've got

```
var User = {
    schema: true,

    attributes: {
        username: {
            type: 'string',
            unique: true,
            required: true
        },

        email: {
            type: 'email',
            unique: true,
            required: true
        },

        password: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            minLength: 8
        },
    }
};

module.exports = User;
```

And when I call

```
exports.register = function (req, res, next) {
    var email = req.param('email')
        , username = req.param('username')
        , password = req.param('password');

    User.create({
            username: username
            , email: email
            , password: password
        }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                if (err.code === 'E_VALIDATION') {
                    if (err.invalidAttributes.email) {
                        req.flash('error', 'Error.Passport.Email.Exists');
                    } else {
                        req.flash('error', 'Error.Passport.User.Exists');
                    }
                }

                return next(err);
            }
        });
    };
};
```

when providing `username` and `email` that already exist in the database, the new entry is stored in the DB, instead of giving me an error msg.

Isn't `User.create()` supposed to take care of checking in the schema attributes rules whether they are unique and then check the records in the DB for a record with a value that already exists?

Comment: Looks like an issue with creating the unique index in mongo, check the message from @particlebanana on this sails-mongo thread https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/issues/152